# Conditional breakpoint not reached on $_ value

Tags: powershell, vscode-debugger, conditional-breakpoint

Can a conditional breakpoint be set on a $_.member value? I am using the following expression, but the breakpoint is never hit. The $_ structure comes from a database record. I know that the 'auser' value is in the data.

```
{if ($_.LoginName -match 'auser') {break}}
```

I have structured this expression after the example at [https://info.sapien.com/index.php/how-to/powershell-studio-howto/setting-conditional-breakpoints#:~:text=To%20set%20a%20conditional%20breakpoint%3A%20When%20creating%20or,instead%20of%20breaking%20%28not%20in%20addition%20to%20breaking%29](https://info.sapien.com/index.php/how-to/powershell-studio-howto/setting-conditional-breakpoints#:%7E:text=To%20set%20a%20conditional%20breakpoint%3A%20When%20creating%20or,instead%20of%20breaking%20%28not%20in%20addition%20to%20breaking%29).

Comment: @AdminOfThings, I take it back. It hit a different breakpoint. After removing the second RIGHT PARENTHESIS character, it still fails to hit the breakpoint.

Comment: Why is this `if` inside a scriptblock? Can you show more of the script?

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-psbreakpoint?view=powershell-7.1#example-5--set-a-breakpoint-depending-on-the-value-of-a-variable) syntax? How and with what do you execute your code?

Comment: I tested this a few ways. Using `$_`  or `$psitem` just seems to not work. Using other variable names doesn't seem to have issues for me.

Comment: @Theo, this is the entire expression scriptblock. I based it on the Sapien article mentioned in the question.

Comment: @stackprotector, I am using Visual Studio Code for debugging as suggested by the `vscode-debugger` tag.